# How to turn off the (apparent) Facebook filters on recent activity?

Tags: facebook

I've noticed that when I look at the "Recent Activity" on my facebook home page, it still filters out people (I assume based on people I don't interact with often?).  How can I turn this off so I really just see the most recent activity for all my friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook recently changed how this works (again).  These instructions are for February 2011.

From your News Feed with "Most Recent" selected, click on **Most Recent** and then **Edit Options**.  In the dialog box, select Show posts from: **All your friends and pages** and press the **Save** button.  It will then show posts from all of your friends and pages, except those listed in the "Hide posts from" section.

[image: Edit Options dialog box]

Comment: Yeah I tried that.  It still seems to filter some out which are *not* on the hide list, but I haven't confirmed that yet.

Answer (score 0):

It filters out activity based on your privacy settings and your friends privacy settings.

[From the Facebook Help Topic.](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=16580)

> **How can I control what Recent Activity Stories display on my
>   profile?**
>
> Recent Activity stories only appear to
>   people who are able to view the
>   original content that they are about,
>   based on privacy setting chosen by the
>   person who posted the content. For
>   example, if you comment on a friend's
>   status, then only people who are
>   permitted to see both your Wall and
>   your friend's status will see a story
>   about it when they look at your Wall.
>
> You cannot completely turn off Recent
>   Activity stories; however, you can:
>
> - Prevent people from seeing certain Recent Activity stories on your
>     profile by [editing individual privacy
>     settings](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=19676).
> - Remove Recent Activity stories by clicking the "Remove" button that
>     appears to the right of the story
>     after you move your mouse over it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think there's a further filter occurring.  How is it that people I'm friends with post status updates that do not show up on my recent activity page?  I have checked the individual privacy settings and have set none; regardless, that should affect who can see *my* updates if I read that correctly.  Why are my friends' updates not appearing?

Comment: @morganpdx - Hmm strange. Are you definitely looking at the Recent Activity not the Top News?

Comment: Definitely.  Top News is just irritating...top according to whom?  Not me! I like my stuff chronological.

Comment: @morganpdx - Ha! I couldn't agree more! I'll have a further dig around and see if I can find anything else.

Comment: I did find a spot where you could specify 'how many friends show up in my stream' or some such. I believe it's in the options drop down for the recent news link. (Bear with me, I'm doing this from memory).  It was set at 250 (more friends than I have).  I increased it to 1000 and that appeared to help *a little bit*.  But not completely...perhaps I should set it to 1,000,000 or something outrageous like that.